# Set upload max file size - isp config

Tags: php

I only have access to ISP Config.

In Custom php.ini settings I have:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Is this correct? It is not working for me.

I get this error with a large image, small images work fine:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error ormisconfiguration and was
>   unable to completeyour request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@devsites.net and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred,and anything you might have
>   done that may havecaused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be availablein the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Errorerror was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: what error you are getting?and in which context its not working?

Comment: Large files cannot be uploaded. Updated original post with error.

Comment: Please look at your log files for a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think it is anything to do with post_max_size = 100M and 
upload_max_filesize = 10M

The Web server (running the Web Site) encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the client (e.g. your Web browser) for access to the requested URL.
This is a 'catch-all' error generated by the Web server. Basically something has gone wrong, but the server can not be more specific about the error condition in its response to the client. In addition to the 500 error notified back to the client, the Web server should generate some kind of internal error log which gives more details of what went wrong. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse these logs.

read detailed explanation here : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

read the following link.that might help you https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from the server. Your server's RAM is not enough for big size images.